# Given a derivative function, a coordinate on original function, can we find a certain limit?

Tags: integration, limits, derivatives, continuity

True or false?

If we're given:
$f'(x) = \frac 1x$ and $f(2) = 9$,
then (true or false): $$\lim \limits_{x \to 2}\frac{{\sqrt {f(x)}}-3}{x-2}= \frac 1{12}$$

(Apologize for fractions, couldn't get them working...)

Comment: Note:  I reformatted this and changed the term in the numerator to $\sqrt {f(x)}$ instead of $\sqrt {f(2)}$.  If I was wrong to do that, please change it back.

Comment: Should note:  the posted solutions correctly address the problem as I edited it (and which is what I assume you intended).  If you did intend $\sqrt {f(2)}$ in the numerator then the answer is $0$ as the function is identically $0$ in a (punctured) neighborhood of $x=2$.

Comment: @lulu: For all $x \not= 2$, in fact.

Comment: @lulu, thank you for fixing this, you were correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

Without L'Hospital, $$\lim \limits_{x \to 2}\frac{{\sqrt {f(x)}}-3}{x-2}=
\lim \limits_{x \to 2}\frac{{f(x)}-9}{x-2}\frac1{{\sqrt {f(x)}}+3}=
f'(2)\frac1{{\sqrt {f(2)}+3}}=
\frac 1{12}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Define $g=\sqrt{f}$. Under the (implicit) assumption that $f$ is indeed differentiable on an interval around $2$ (with the expression $1/x$ you gave) then $g$ is differentiable as well; can you compute the expression for $g^\prime$, as a function of $f$ and $f^\prime$?

> Recall that $(a\circ b)^\prime(x) = b^\prime(x)\cdot (a^\prime\circ b)(x)$, provided all derivatives are well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

Can you solve for $f(x)$? Please verify that $f(x) = \ln(x/2) + 9$

After that, check that the above limit is indeed $1/12$

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward L'Hôpital (and chain rule) gives:

$$
\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\sqrt{f(x)}-3}{x-2}
    = \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{f'(x)}{2\sqrt{f(x)}}
    = \frac{1/2}{2\sqrt{9}} = \frac{1}{12}
$$

Comment: The chain rule is enough. This is only asking to compute $g^\prime(2)$ for $g=\sqrt{f}$, no need for L'Hopital...

Comment: Just offering a different approach to the same answer.